# Why is this Powershell command failing when running in my Dockerfile

Tags: powershell, dockerfile

I'm issuing the following command within my Dockerfile

```
RUN $pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $($Env:certPassword) -AsPlainText -Force
RUN $cert = Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath c:\cert\mycert.pfx -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My" -Password $pwd
```

It's throwing the following error...

```
Import-PfxCertificate : Cannot bind parameter 'Password'. Cannot convert the
"C:\" value of type "System.Management.Automation.PathInfo" to type
"System.Security.SecureString".
At line:1 char:122
+ ... _cta_tech.pfx -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -Password $pwd
+ ~~~~ + CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (:) [Import-PfxCertificate], ParameterBindingException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.CertificateServices.Commands.ImportPfxCertificate
```

I've tried wrapping it in single quotes, double quotes, escaping the "" as "\", passing it as a variable, etc. It seems like it doesn't like the -FilePath parameter but I can't figure out what it wants.

If I run the command directly within my container with a powershell bash it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Separate `RUN` commands run in *separate shell sessions***, so you **cannot use one `RUN` command to create state for another.**

Therefore, if you  need to use *multiple* statements, pass them to a *single* `RUN` command with the statements separated with `;`

However, in your case a single statement will do, using `(...)` to pass the output from the `ConvertTo-SecureString` call directly as an argument to `Import-PfxCertificate`'s `-Password` parameter:

```
RUN $cert = Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath c:\cert\mycert.pfx -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Env:certPassword -AsPlainText -Force)
```

---

Two asides:

- `$pwd` is an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#pwd) reflecting the current location (directory) and shouldn't be used for custom purposes (surprisingly, you technically *can*, however).

  - It is because your `RUN` commands executed in *independent* sessions you saw the error quoted in the question: in the second `RUN` command, `$pwd` was the *automatic variable*, and expanded to `C:\`, i.e. the current location at the time.
- You can replace `$cert =` with `$null =`  if you simply want to *suppress* the output from `Import-PfxCertificate` (without processing `$cert` further in the *same* `RUN` command, its use is pointless).
- There is a stray `"` in the 2nd `RUN` command in your question, which I've removed from the solution.

  - In the PowerShell [*CLI*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) call that happens behind the scenes, this stray `"` is effectively ignored (though it would cause a problem if the command were executed *in-session*).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that each RUN executed in its own context. Learn something new.

The stray double quote wasn't in my code but in an effort to sanitize my actual code it made it in.

The $cert variable is used so I can use it in a New-IISSiteBinding call that I didn't include in this code example.